# trying to read specific columns from multiple csv with fread and apply

Tags: r, data.table

Here is the situation, I have many csv files, say, 20 of them. Each of them has different column names. So I built a map for them.

```
map
#   variable location
#          A   1
#          B   1
#          C   2
```

I was trying to read them all once, so I have a code like this:

```
Table <- rbindlist(
           apply(map, 1, function(x) {
               fil <- paste0(x[2], ".csv")
               sel <- x[1]
               fread(file = fil,  select = sel)
         }
```

When it is done, I get a data.table with 1 column of all data. If I use `rbind`, I get a large matrix of wanted element, but can't be converted into the data.table form I need. How can I make it happen? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Do you have file with names `1.csv' `2.csv` ?  `map` is name of a function  `rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(map)), function(i) fread(file = paste0(map[i, 2], ".csv"), select = map[i, 1])))` assuming that 'variable' column is `character` class

Comment: yes, the file name is ok. I can read the data, but can't extract it out.

Comment: Please try the code in the comment

Comment: Or another option is `Map(function(x, y) fread(file = x, select = y), paste0(map$location, ".csv"), map$variable)`  Or more compactly `rbindlist(Map(fread,  file = paste0(map$location, ".csv"), select = map$variable))`

Comment: That could be the reason because with `apply`, the `factor` gets coerced to integer values and didn't work

Comment: The Map way is working. I also found the variable was factor and it was part of the trouble. After Map, it became a Large list, so I simply ```as.data.table```, while the colnames needs minor treatment. Thanks, @akrun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the columns that are `factor` class in the dataset 'map'.  When we use `apply`, it is converted to a `matrix` and the `factor` columns get coerced to `integer` values and that causes the mismatch.  One option is to convert to `character` class.  This can be done more compactly with `Map`

```
rbindlist(Map(fread, file = paste0(map$location, ".csv"),
                   select = as.character(map$variable)))
```